# Using ethzasl_icp_mapping in indigo with velodyne HDL-32E

Tags: ros, 3d-slam, ethzasl-icp-mapping, ros-indigo, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use ethzasl_icp_mapping on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo.
Following the steps how I proceed :

1. first, I clone the :[ethzasl_icp_mapping](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping) in my catkin_ws
2. I run catkin_make, no build file is generated of "ethzasl_icp_mapping_project"

Here are couple of the questions I have:

1. can someone give me the exact steps to run the project
2. I want to use point cloud from Velodyne HDL-32E

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236321/using-ethzasl_icp_mapping-in-indigo-with-velodyne-hdl-32e/) by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tarantula-7](https://answers.ros.org/users/26921/tarantula-7/) on 2016-11-17**:
Could you finally succeed in using with Velodyne HDL-32E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

to compile the "ethzasl_icp_mapping" library in "ROS indigo" under "Ubuntu 14.04"

it is necessary do the following in `catkin_ws / src` :

```
1- git clone -b indigo_devel https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping.git
2- git clone -b release/indigo/libnabo https://github.com/ethz-asl/libnabo-release.git
3- git clone -b release/indigo/libpointmatcher https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher-release.git
```

4- in

> `catkin_ws`

execute: `catkin_make_isolated`

5- in `catkin_ws / devel_isolated` execute: `source setup.bash`

---

Originally posted by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) with karma: 76 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0